# Graphics3D: the box vertices do not coincide with triangle

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have drawn a triangle using `Line` graphics primitive and `Graphics3D` function:

```
 Graphics3D[Line[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}], 
 Axes -> False, Boxed -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

But in the shape I get, the vertices of triangle do not coincide with the vertices of the box, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think you can try `PlotRangePadding -> 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment is right, but here is a thought. If you'd like a cube you should use `Cuboid` and leave the 3D box for the role it plays - to put things in a better 3D perspective (if needed). Then you precisely control all coordinates. You could try something like

```
Graphics3D[{
  {Red, Opacity[.7], Polygon[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]},
  {Opacity[.2], Cuboid[{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}]}
  }, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by [xslittlegrass](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1364/xslittlegrass) you can get coincident vertices by instructing `Graphics3D` not to use padding of the plot range, by using `PlotRangePadding -> 0`.

`AspectRatio` controls the two dimensional image aspect ratio rather the proportions of the three dimensional rendering which is what I expect you intended; for that use `BoxRatios`.

Specifying `Boxed -> True` should (by default) produce a graph without axis lines shown, therefore the `Axes -> False` option is redundant.

```
Graphics3D[
 Line[Tuples[{0, 1}, 3][[{5, 3, 2, 5}]]],
 Boxed -> True,
 PlotRangePadding -> 0
]
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much.

Comment: @Ahmad You're welcome.